# Why does "creating" a tag require reputation?

Tags: discussion, tags, reputation

I just wanted to tag my question ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083724/why-does-big-endian-end-with-the-little-byte)) with BigEndian, LittleEndian and Endianness, because that's what it's about. But apparently I need 1500 reputation to do so. Why's that? Why do I need that much reputation to improve my question?

Comment: I'd say that `BigEndian` and `LittleEndian` are not broad enough to be their own tag. `Endianness` is better, but still too specific. It really should be something more broad, like `memory`, `memory-management` or even `computer-architecture`. Tags don't really improve a question when they're so specific that there might only be a couple questions tagged with it.

Comment: Because we don't want new users with no experience creating tons of nonsensical, useless or meaningless tags. Hopefully by the time they've earned the privilege to create a tag, they'll have enough experience here to understand how the site works, how to research existing tags before automatically creating a new one, and have determined that some tags that might appear to be useful or necessary are in fact not so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not supposed to use tags as keywords. That's not the use of them. Their main propose is to connect answerers with the questions they can answer. Creating tags is mostly responsibility of the answerers after the questions were asked, since the tagging is meant for them.

> Why do I need that much reputation to improve my question?

Applying tags frivolously, without a good reason, would do the opposite: it will weight down the quality of your question, since people won't understand why were those tags applied, and do one of two, ignore the question because they don't understand the topic the tag is trying to convey, or come and edit those meaningless tags, which just serve to attract the wrong kind of audience.

Your question was already answered with a single tag, that means that that tag was more meaningful and valuable that any other tag you could have applied.

Comment: `You are not supposed to use tags as keywords.` That's the explanation I was looking for.  I thought of tags as keywords. Thank you for clarifying that.

Answer (score 6):

> *"Why's that? Why do I need that much reputation to improve my question?"*

First point you don't need tags to improve your question, just go and make it clearer by editing, and adding additional information and context.

Why you can't create new tags is, because we want to have at least *"halfway trusted"* users being able to create new tags. 
These should serve as a signpost for future research, and have to be created with caution. Also they should have relevance for a major number of similar questions, and sort out ambiguity against main stream language tag questions.

Last but not least, you should be able to create a minimal tag wiki for newly created tags, which is mostly beyond skills of new users here.

Allowing low rep users, who aren't familiar with the site's policies, or how tagging actually works, to create new tags would result in numerous tags which won't be helpful for any future research.

Comment: case in point, the aforementioned suggested tags

Comment: "which won't be helpful for any answerer" FTFY.